# How to iterate over the non-zero values of a sparse array

Tags: julia, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse array in Julia and would like to iterate over its non-zero entries. What's a good way of doing this?

So far, I have:

```
using SparseArrays

a = sprandn(20,20,0.3)

for (x,y,v) in a
  print(x,y,v)
end
```

Comment: It really depends on what you want to do. Do you need the indices of the values? If not, you can just iterate over `nonzeros(A)`.

Comment: @fredrikekre: I need the indices. The values themselves are not important in my use case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`findnz`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/SparseArrays/#SparseArrays.findnz) function returns a tuple containing arrays of the x, y, and value components of the sparse matrix. That is,

```
findnz(a) gives ([x1, x2, x3, ...], [y1, y2, y3, ...], [v1, v2, v3, ...])
```

You can use this like an iterator as follows:

```
for (x,y,v) in zip(findnz(a)...)
  println(x,' ',y,' ',v)
end
```

Comment: This is very nice and compact; but for a simple loop (such as adding all matrix entries) it's about 10x slower than @Kristoffer Carlsson's solution

Answer (score 5):

Here is a direct way to do it

```
using SparseArrays

function print_nz(A)
    for col in 1:size(A, 2)
        for r in nzrange(A, col)
            println(rowvals(A)[r], ' ', col, ' ',  nonzeros(A)[r])
        end
    end
end
```

and an example of it being used:

```
julia> A = [1 2 1
            0 0 1
            3 0 0];

julia> print_nz(sparse(A))
1 1 1
3 1 3
1 2 2
1 3 1
2 3 1
```